# How to send multiple props and execute function for each?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a scenario by which I will be getting two separate times in minutes format, for that am using a function to convert it as 24 hours format without separator, and now am using momentjs to convert it to the required format. Everything works perfectly, but the problem is I'm calling the function two times in react native flat list, is there any way to doing this work in a single function?

My Function

```
DepartureTimeFormat (props){

        let quotient = Math.floor(props / 60);
        let remainder = props % 60;
        let journeyday = Math.floor(quotient / 24);
        let hour = quotient % 24;
        let minutes = remainder;
    
        let strHour = String(hour).length < 2 ? '0' + String(hour) : String(hour)
        let strMinutes = String(minutes).length < 2 ? '0' + String(minutes) : String(minutes)
    
        let departureTime = strHour + strMinutes
    
        return(
            <Text>
                {moment(departureTime, 'hmm').format('h:mm A')}
            </Text>
        )
    }
```

So I am passing this on my flat list as

```
{this.DepartureTimeFormat(item.departureTime)}
```

And I'm getting an output as 7:00 Pm which is good

And for arrival time, I again use

```
{this.DepartureTimeFormat(item.arrivalTime)}
```

so it outputs as 7:30 Am which is also good

So how to do this is a single function call? As I'm getting two parameters for arrival time and departure time am doing two function call, is there a way to send two props into function and map it to return two output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable number of arguments to your function using the spread syntax, and so you'll get the dates as an array. Then you can use `map` to iterate those for doing the conversion.

NB: use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) for padding with zero

Code:

```
DepartureTimeFormat (...dates) {
    return dates.map(function (props) {
        let quotient = Math.floor(props / 60);
        let remainder = props % 60;
        let journeyday = Math.floor(quotient / 24);
        let hour = quotient % 24;
        let minutes = remainder;
    
        let strHour = String(hour).padStart(2, "0");
        let strMinutes = String(minutes).padStart(2, "0");
    
        let departureTime = strHour + strMinutes
    
        return(
            <Text>
                {moment(departureTime, 'hmm').format('h:mm A')}
            </Text>
        )
    });
}
```

Now you can call:

```
this.DepartureTimeFormat(item.departureTime, item.arrivalTime)
```

...while it would also still work with just one argument.

Possibly the function and variable should get a better name, as now the function is not only about *departure*...

Comment: It, works but now the results look like, it first runs on arrivalTime and displays and second it runs on depatureTime and displays? How to spit the output ? ```expected : 07:10 Am 12:00 Pm``` but the result is like ```Result: 07:10 Am 12:00 Pm 07:10 Am 12:00 Pm ```

Comment: It returns two text elements. It all depends how they render (css).  If they have max width and appear columnwise you can get this...

Comment: I understand the work around, but is that the only way ? or is there any of returning the outputs separately ?

Comment: It is returning the outputs separately. The return value is actually an array of two outputs. reactjs can handle arrays, but you can also extract the two outputs from the returned array and do your thing with it separately. Not sure what you mean with "work around" though.

Comment: Understood, thankyou, While implementing this, am getting Each child in a list should have a unique "key" , and am damn sure my flatlist have unique id. When i remove the above function the errors goes away, Any ide why its happening ?

Comment: I have no idea without seeing your code. If you have a new question, I suggest you press the "Ask Question" button and provide the information to reproduce the problem you encounter.